# How can I define a type for a css color in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following example code snippet:

```
type Color = string;

interface Props {
    color: Color;
    text: string;
}

function Badge(props: Props) {
    return `<div style="color:${props.color}">${props.text}</div>`;
}

var badge = Badge({
    color: '#F00',
    text: 'Danger'
});

console.log(badge);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Props%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Badge(props%3A%20Props)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%60%3Cdiv%20style%3D%22color%3A%24%7Bprops.color%7D%22%3E%24%7Bprops.text%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E%60%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20badge%20%3D%20Badge(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20'%23F00'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20text%3A%20'Danger'%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(badge)%3B)

I'm trying to get a build error if the color is invalid, like so:

```
var badge = Badge({
    color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100)',
    text: 'Danger'
});
```

Is there a way to define `Color` so that it allows only strings matching one of the following patterns?

- `#FFF`
- `#FFFFFF`
- `rgb(5, 5, 5)`
- `rgba(5, 5, 5, 1)`
- `hsa(5, 5, 5)`

I realize that there are colors like `red` and `white` but that might make this harder to answer if `Color` can accept those.

Comment: For someone looking for an answer I've implemented color checking type in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68068969/3388225) to another similar question.

Answer (score 80):

```
type RGB = `rgb(${number}, ${number}, ${number})`;
type RGBA = `rgba(${number}, ${number}, ${number}, ${number})`;
type HEX = `#${string}`;

type Color = RGB | RGBA | HEX;
```

`${...}` notation is available on new (^4.1) ts versions.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

Comment: I'd say this is definitely the best answer in 2022

Comment: looks great, but how do you convert them to/from a string?
typescript hat some problems in my case, so i had to add | string to the type
type Color = HEX | string;

Comment: How does this cover `red`, `green` or `currentColor`, which are all valid HTML color values?

Comment: You can make all of these types more specific. As written, you could use `rgb(12345,6789,0)` or `#potato`.

There's a good answer here for fixing that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74514303/1204068

Answer (score 15):

There was a proposal for [a type of string which matches a pattern](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) (regex or something else), but that proposal haven't come to fruition yet.

As a result, what you ask for is unfortunately impossible as of TypeScript 2.2.

Comment: just to troll a bit: it is not impossible... it would simply require tooooooone and a bit of code like `type Color = '#100000' | '#200000' | ... | '#FFFFFF' | rgb(1, 0, 0) | rgb(2, 0, 0) | ...` ;)

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, and writing an automated script to generate that doesn't seem very implausible (there is, after all, a script to generate `.d.ts` files from `.css` files for types CSS modules). But I somehow don't think that's what OP wanted :).

Comment: @gaa I decided to do this... It crashes the typescript server, seen here https://github.com/biw/ts-color-type

Comment: @biw I would report a bug just to check how they handle it 

Answer (score 8):

You can't do this yet in a general sense, but you can use constants and string literal types if you have a well defined set of colors:

```
type Color = "#FFFFFF" | "#FF0000" | "#0000FF";
const WHITE: Color = "#FFFFFF";
const RED: Color = "#FF0000";
const BLUE: Color = "#0000FF";
```

Obviously, this won't be practical if you want to allow *any* color, but in reality you probably *do* want to have re-usable color variables anyway.

In my project I use a script to generate a similar file from my `colors.css` file which defines a bunch of CSS properties:

```
:root {
  --primary-red: #ff0000;
  --secondary-red: #993333;
  /* etc */
}
```

Which gets converted to:

```
export const primaryRed: Color = "#ff0000";
export const secondaryRed: Color = "#993333";
// etc
export type Color = "#ff0000" | "#993333" // | etc...
```

And I'd use it like:

```
import {primaryRed} from "./Colors.ts";

interface BadgeProps {
    color: Color;
    text: string;
}  

var badge = Badge({
    color: primaryRed,
    text: 'Danger'
});
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're using React in your example. A simple option may be to import `CSSProperties` and access the `color` property.

```
import { CSSProperties } from "react";

const Entry = ({color}: {color: CSSProperties["color"]}) => {
  return (
    <div style={{color: color}}>
      This text will be colored.
    </div>
  );
};
```

The benefit of this is it can easily be provided any form of color: named colors like `yellow`, `aliceblue`, or `powderblue`, hex values, RGB, HSL, or any string that is valid CSS.

This is functionally the same as using `string` but with a more expressive type usage. If you need to use type guarding, go with the first and accepted answer here.

Answer (score 7):

My 2 cents:

```
type RGB = `rgb(${string})`
type RGBA = `rgba(${string})`
type HEX = `#${string}`
type HSL = `hsl(${string})`
type HSLA = `hsla(${string})`
type VAR = `var(${string})`

type CssGlobals = 'inherit' | 'initial' | 'revert' | 'unset'

export type CssColor =
  | 'currentColor'
  | 'transparent'
  | RGB
  | RGBA
  | HEX
  | HSL
  | HSLA
  | VAR
  | CssGlobals
```

Answer (score 4):

It is theoretically possible with union types, however if you JUST do hex codes, you have well over 16,000,000 possible combinations, and typescript (4.6.3 at least) does not like that idea.

It has been on the backburner for MS for over a year now
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42790

Answer (score 4):

A runtime check for color validity `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')` would be the best suitable solution for now, since TypeScript (as of 4.8.4) cannot handle  such complex types.

I tried making a HEX color type, which seems like it should work if you just read the code as a human, but actually it fails with anything more overloaded than a short format CSS HEX color (like #fff):

```
type HexLetter = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f';
type HexDigit = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;
type HexPart = HexLetter | HexDigit;
type HexEncodedNumber = `${HexPart}${HexPart}`;

const hexEncodedNumberTestForSuccess: HexEncodedNumber = '0f';
const hexEncodedNumberTestForError: HexEncodedNumber = 'r3'; //* Type '"r3"' is not assignable to type 'HexEncodedNumber'.
// A single HexEncodedNumber works!
// This means we can have type safety defining a number from 0 to 255 in HEX format.

/** Length: 3 */
type HexCodeShort = `${HexPart}${HexPart}${HexPart}`;
/** Length: 6 */
type HexCodeClassic = `${HexEncodedNumber}${HexEncodedNumber}${HexEncodedNumber}`; //! Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent. ts(2590)
// HexCodeClassic evaluates to 'any' type.
/** Length: 8 */
type HexCodeWithAlpha = `${HexCodeClassic}${HexEncodedNumber}`; // So this is `${any}aa` | `${any}ab` etc.
/** Length: 3 (short) | 6 (classic) | 8 (alpha) */
type HexCodeModern = HexCodeShort | HexCodeClassic | HexCodeWithAlpha; // Just 'any'.

type HexCodeCss = `#${HexCodeModern}`;
const hexCodeCssTestForEmergedAny: HexCodeCss = '#ICanSetAnythingHereWithNoTrouble'; // `#${any}`.
// Full CSS HEX code does not work.
```

So, you can only ensure full type safety for 3 characters of a CSS color, not even considering uppercase letters.

As a workaround, you can construct a function that accepts `r, g, b, a` all of type HexEncodedNumber, and TypeScript will type-check the parameters, but the `ReturnType<>` of that function will be just `string`, or `any` if you try to add `as const` or even 'as `#${string}`' to the return statement.

The RGB situation should be around the same, as it's the same possible number of combinations.

Comment: `[ts] Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.` at `type HexCodeClassic`

Comment: not unexpected i guess. perhaps the sheer number of permutations calls for a type guard instead?

Comment: @JosephBeuys'Mum looks like this error is already mentioned in the comment, in the end of the line where `type HexCodeClassic` is declared.

Perhaps I should have kept the horizontal length of the code block a bit smaller.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an answer (see above for that) but here's something you might find useful:

```
type CssColorNames =
  | 'AliceBlue'
  | 'AntiqueWhite'
  | 'Aqua'
  | 'Aquamarine'
  | 'Azure'
  | 'Beige'
  | 'Bisque'
  | 'Black'
  | 'BlanchedAlmond'
  | 'Blue'
  | 'BlueViolet'
  | 'Brown'
  | 'BurlyWood'
  | 'CadetBlue'
  | 'Chartreuse'
  | 'Chocolate'
  | 'Coral'
  | 'CornflowerBlue'
  | 'Cornsilk'
  | 'Crimson'
  | 'Cyan'
  | 'DarkBlue'
  | 'DarkCyan'
  | 'DarkGoldenRod'
  | 'DarkGray'
  | 'DarkGrey'
  | 'DarkGreen'
  | 'DarkKhaki'
  | 'DarkMagenta'
  | 'DarkOliveGreen'
  | 'DarkOrange'
  | 'DarkOrchid'
  | 'DarkRed'
  | 'DarkSalmon'
  | 'DarkSeaGreen'
  | 'DarkSlateBlue'
  | 'DarkSlateGray'
  | 'DarkSlateGrey'
  | 'DarkTurquoise'
  | 'DarkViolet'
  | 'DeepPink'
  | 'DeepSkyBlue'
  | 'DimGray'
  | 'DimGrey'
  | 'DodgerBlue'
  | 'FireBrick'
  | 'FloralWhite'
  | 'ForestGreen'
  | 'Fuchsia'
  | 'Gainsboro'
  | 'GhostWhite'
  | 'Gold'
  | 'GoldenRod'
  | 'Gray'
  | 'Grey'
  | 'Green'
  | 'GreenYellow'
  | 'HoneyDew'
  | 'HotPink'
  | 'IndianRed'
  | 'Indigo'
  | 'Ivory'
  | 'Khaki'
  | 'Lavender'
  | 'LavenderBlush'
  | 'LawnGreen'
  | 'LemonChiffon'
  | 'LightBlue'
  | 'LightCoral'
  | 'LightCyan'
  | 'LightGoldenRodYellow'
  | 'LightGray'
  | 'LightGrey'
  | 'LightGreen'
  | 'LightPink'
  | 'LightSalmon'
  | 'LightSeaGreen'
  | 'LightSkyBlue'
  | 'LightSlateGray'
  | 'LightSlateGrey'
  | 'LightSteelBlue'
  | 'LightYellow'
  | 'Lime'
  | 'LimeGreen'
  | 'Linen'
  | 'Magenta'
  | 'Maroon'
  | 'MediumAquaMarine'
  | 'MediumBlue'
  | 'MediumOrchid'
  | 'MediumPurple'
  | 'MediumSeaGreen'
  | 'MediumSlateBlue'
  | 'MediumSpringGreen'
  | 'MediumTurquoise'
  | 'MediumVioletRed'
  | 'MidnightBlue'
  | 'MintCream'
  | 'MistyRose'
  | 'Moccasin'
  | 'NavajoWhite'
  | 'Navy'
  | 'OldLace'
  | 'Olive'
  | 'OliveDrab'
  | 'Orange'
  | 'OrangeRed'
  | 'Orchid'
  | 'PaleGoldenRod'
  | 'PaleGreen'
  | 'PaleTurquoise'
  | 'PaleVioletRed'
  | 'PapayaWhip'
  | 'PeachPuff'
  | 'Peru'
  | 'Pink'
  | 'Plum'
  | 'PowderBlue'
  | 'Purple'
  | 'RebeccaPurple'
  | 'Red'
  | 'RosyBrown'
  | 'RoyalBlue'
  | 'SaddleBrown'
  | 'Salmon'
  | 'SandyBrown'
  | 'SeaGreen'
  | 'SeaShell'
  | 'Sienna'
  | 'Silver'
  | 'SkyBlue'
  | 'SlateBlue'
  | 'SlateGray'
  | 'SlateGrey'
  | 'Snow'
  | 'SpringGreen'
  | 'SteelBlue'
  | 'Tan'
  | 'Teal'
  | 'Thistle'
  | 'Tomato'
  | 'Turquoise'
  | 'Violet'
  | 'Wheat'
  | 'White'
  | 'WhiteSmoke'
  | 'Yellow'
  | 'YellowGreen';
```

Comment: libs are not answers - hence this being a comment - but: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csstype

Answer (score 1):

Install `color-types` can help you.

```
npm i -D color-types
```

Then add library to file `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["color-types"]
  }
}
```

#### Usages:

```ts
const color: ColorName = 'red';
const color: HEX       = '#ff0000';
const color: RGB       = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
const color: RGBA      = 'rgb(255 0 0 / 100%)' | 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';
const color: HSL       = 'hsl(0deg 100% 50%)';
const color: HSLA      = 'hsla(0rad, 100%, 50%, 1)';
const color: HWB       = 'hwb(0turn 0% 0%)';

const color: RGBObject  = { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 } || { red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0 };
const color: RGBAObject = { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1 } || { red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1 };
const color: HSLObject  = { h: 0, s: 100, l: 50 } || { hue: 0, saturation: 100, lightness: 50 };
const color: HSLAObject = { h: 0, s: 100, l: 50, a: 1 } || { hue: 0, saturation: 100, lightness: 50, alpha: 1 };
const color: HWBObject  = { h: 0, w: 0, b: 0 } || { hue: 0, whiteness: 0, blackness: 0 } || { hue: 0, whiteness: 0, blackness: 0, aplha: 1 };

// All of type color
const color: Color = 'red' || '#ff0000' || 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse that the string contains only valid chars, like

```js
type hexSymbol =
  | "0"
  | "1"
  | "2"
  | "3"
  | "4"
  | "5"
  | "6"
  | "7"
  | "8"
  | "9"
  | "a"
  | "b"
  | "c"
  | "d"
  | "e"
  | "f";

type SkipHashSymbol<T> = T extends `#${infer Rest}` ? Rest : T;
```

Then go recursively through your string

```
type isHexSymbolsString<T> = T extends `${hexSymbol}${infer Rest}`
  ? Rest extends ""
    ? true
    : isHexSymbolsString<Rest>
  : false;

type isHex<T extends string> = isHexSymbolsString<
  SkipHashSymbol<T>
> extends true
  ? true
  : false;

type valid = isHex<"#123abc">;
type invalid = isHex<"#qwe">;
```