# How to type a color prop?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, colors

My component accepts an `overlay` prop that is supposed to be a valid CSS color.

When I `CTRL + Click` on a `color` property in style object, the type definition comes from a `csstype` folder inside node_modules. The type definition for CSS color property is defined as `Property.Color`. I imported that type into my component and used it as my `overlay` prop's type but it ends up being `any` when I try to use that component.

My component's type definition:

```
import { Property } from "../node_modules/csstype/index";


export interface BlurredComponentProps {
  overlay?: Property.Color;
}
```

Here is how it looks when I use the component:

[image]

So my question is, how to properly type a prop that is supposed to take only valid CSS colors and give error if non-color value is given?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I define a type for a css color in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584228/how-can-i-define-a-type-for-a-css-color-in-typescript)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This one is pretty hard to encode in TypeScript's type system. I believe a full fledged parser can do a better job in both speed and accuracy.

---

Anyway, if you really want to get some typecheking for your `color` values from typescript then let's start with w3c color property [description](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color#Description):

```
Values: <color value> | <color keyword> | currentColor | transparent | inherit
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBznnN) for those who don't need explanations and what to look right into the code.

---

Well, `color keyword`, `currentColor`, `transparent` and `inherit` are pretty straightforward:

```ts
type Color = ColorValue | ColorKeyword | 'currentColor' | 'transparent' | 'inherit'

type ColorKeyword =
    | "black"
    | "silver"
    | "gray"
    ...
    | "rebeccapurple"
```

The tricky part is `<color value>`:

```
The color can be specified as

* a hexadecimal RGB value: #faf or #ffaaff
* a RGB value: rgb(255, 160, 255) or rgb(100%, 62.5%, 100%)
      Each value is from 0 to 255, or from 0% to 100%.
* a RGBA value: rgba(255, 160, 255, 1) or rgba(100%, 62.5%, 100%, 1)
      This variant includes an “alpha” component to allow 
      specification of the opacity of a color. Values are 
      in the range 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque).
* a HSL value: hsl(0, 100%, 50%)
      A triple (hue, saturation, lightness). hue is an 
      angle in degrees. saturation and lightness are 
      percentages (0-100%).
* a HSLA value: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 1)
      This variant includes an “alpha” component to allow 
      specification of the opacity of a color. Values are 
      in the range 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque).
```

`hexadecimal RGB value` is still ok-ish:

```ts
type HexDigit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f'

type Hex3 = `${HexDigit}${HexDigit}${HexDigit}`

type RGBColor<T extends string> = 
  Lowercase<T> extends `#${Hex3}`
      ? T
      : Lowercase<T> extends `#${Hex3}${infer Rest}`
        ? Rest extends Hex3
            ? T
            : never
        : never
```

We have to introduce type variable `T`. Otherwise 'flat' union type:

```ts
type RGBColor = `#${Hex3}` | `#${Hex3}${Hex3}`
```

is going to consist of `16^3 + 16^6` constituents that's far beyound `100000` typescript limit for union types.

Let's introduce some helper types to work with numbers. We have to check the percents are not greater than `100%` and end with `%` character.

```ts
type DecDigit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
type Digits0to4 = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4'

type OnlyDecDigits<T extends string> = 
    T extends `${DecDigit}${infer Rest}`
        ? Rest extends ''
            ? 1
            : OnlyDecDigits<Rest>
        : never

type IsDecNumber<T extends string> =
    T extends `${infer Integer}.${infer Fractional}`
        ? Integer extends ''
            ? OnlyDecDigits<Fractional>
            : Fractional extends ''
                ? OnlyDecDigits<Integer>
                : OnlyDecDigits<Integer> & OnlyDecDigits<Fractional>
        : OnlyDecDigits<T>

type IntegerPart<T extends string> =
    T extends `${infer I}.${infer F}`
        ? I
        : T

type IsInteger<T extends string> = 
    1 extends IsDecNumber<T>
        ? T extends IntegerPart<T> 
            ? 1 
            : never
        : never

type Less100<T extends string> = 
    IsDecNumber<T> extends 1
        ? IntegerPart<T> extends `${DecDigit}` | `${DecDigit}${DecDigit}` | '100'
            ? 1
            : never
        : never

type IsPercent<T extends string> =
    '0' extends T
        ? 1
        : T extends `${infer P}%` 
            ? Less100<P> 
            : never
```

Also color values must be integers and not greater than `255`:

```ts
type Color255<T extends string> =
    1 extends IsInteger<T>
        ? T extends `${DecDigit}` 
                  | `${DecDigit}${DecDigit}` 
                  | `1${DecDigit}${DecDigit}` 
                  | `2${Digits0to4}${DecDigit}`
                  | `25${Digits0to4 | '5'}`
            ? 1
            : never
        : never
```

so, any color value can be encoded as an integer number in `[0..255]` range or a percent:

```ts
type IsColorValue<T extends string> = IsPercent<T> | Color255<T>
```

Adding utility `Trim` type to trim extra spaces on both ends:

```ts
type WhiteSpace = ' '
type Trim<T> = T extends `${WhiteSpace}${infer U}` 
    ? Trim<U> 
    : T extends `${infer U}${WhiteSpace}` 
        ? Trim<U> 
        : T;
```

That's enough for `rgb`:

```ts
type RGB<T extends string> = 
    T extends `rgb(${infer R},${infer G},${infer B})` 
        ? '111' extends `${IsColorValue<Trim<R>>}${IsColorValue<Trim<G>>}${IsColorValue<Trim<B>>}`
            ? T
            : never
        : never
```

For `rgba`/`hsla` we'll need opacity. Here we just ask for any valid number or a percent:

```ts
type Opacity<T extends string> = IsDecNumber<T> | IsPercent<T>
```

Now we can check `rgba` values:

```ts
type RGBA<T extends string> =
    T extends `rgba(${infer R},${infer G},${infer B},${infer O})`
        ? '1111' extends `${IsColorValue<Trim<R>>}${IsColorValue<Trim<G>>}${IsColorValue<Trim<B>>}${Opacity<Trim<O>>}`
            ? T
            : never
        : never
```

Adding degree checker for `hsl`/`hsla`:

```ts
type Degree<T extends string> =
    1 extends IsInteger<T>
        ? T extends `${DecDigit}`
                  | `${DecDigit}${DecDigit}`
                  | `${'1' | '2'}${DecDigit}${DecDigit}`
                  | `3${Digits0to4 | '5'}${DecDigit}`
                  | '360'
            ? 1
            : never
        : never
```

and finally we can cover the last cases:

```ts
type HSL<T extends string> =
    T extends `hsl(${infer H},${infer S},${infer L})`
        ? `111` extends `${Degree<Trim<H>>}${IsPercent<Trim<S>>}${IsPercent<Trim<L>>}`
            ? T
            : never
        :never

type HSLA<T extends string> =
    T extends `hsla(${infer H},${infer S},${infer L},${infer O})`
        ? `1111` extends `${Degree<Trim<H>>}${IsPercent<Trim<S>>}${IsPercent<Trim<L>>}${Opacity<Trim<O>>}`
            ? T
            : never
        :never
```

So our final type will look like that:

```ts
type ColorValue<T extends string> = HexColor<T> | RGB<T> | RGBA<T> | HSL<T> | HSLA<T>

type Color<T extends string> = ColorValue<T> | ColorKeyword | 'currentColor' | 'transparent' | 'inherit'
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NBznnN)

Comment: Wow, round of applause for this answer!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, can you say how you'd go about checking the type of an array of colors?

Something like this won't work, but this is to provide some context on what I'm trying to achieve:

```lang-ts
const myColorArray: Color[] = ['#fff', '#000', 'red']
```

Thank you!