# How to use union with string type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to create custom type in typescript like this:

`color?: 'textPrimary' | 'textSecondary' | string;`

so we have some default value and also other strings.

but typescript convert it to `string | undefined`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: maybe you are looking for an interface?

Comment: I don't understand why a type would be of two specific strings and also of generic `string`. The compiler will always allow any string in it. How do you intend to use it? It's being converted to a string because string contains those two specific string types. It's also undefined likely because you are not compiling in strict mode where nulls/undefined must be checked.

Comment: @MrJami Why an interface? Please be sure to add reasoning to your comments.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064202/how-to-type-a-color-prop

Comment: @JuanMendes I want to have some default values and also can pass others sting as values. 'textPrimary' and 'textSecondary' are predefined color, so I can use editor intelligence.

Comment: I see, you would like the editor to suggest those two values but accept any string... This seems to kind of works already... Try hitting ctrl+space when your cursor is within the quotes.

Comment: I knew how to use editor suggestion :) but it does not suggest those values :)

Comment: @BeHappy Yes, I was using the TS playground and it did seem to suggest those values. However, it also suggested all words that had been typed on the page... :(

Comment: @JuanMendes :(((

Comment: Please see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048124/2887218) to the question this duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

As Ben commented, there's no need to define a type for those extra values you want to fall back, as they are also of type `string`.

In any case, you may be interested in using [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) so you can store those 'default values' you are trying to save. This is helpful for the future of your code, so if there's a need to change those values to another default string, you can only change the `enum` and not go to each hardcoded string and changing them one by one.

Do something like this:

```
enum defaultClasses {
    primary = 'textPrimary',
    secondary = 'textSecondary'
}

class baseProp {
    color?: defaultClasses | string
}

const prop = new baseProp()
prop.color = defaultClasses.primary
console.log(prop.color) # 'textPrimary'
```

Comment: Great thinking outside the box!

Comment: I want to use as React component props. I am not sure if creating instance of class is good or not.

Comment: The `class` was only an example, you should be fine using them when creating new types anywhere. Note though that there are 2 different ways you cant type-check your React props, one is using Typescript which will only validate them at Compilation, and the other is using `prop-types` which validates at runtime, [this question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746028/proptypes-in-a-typescript-react-application).

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make sense. A 'type' is simply a *description of all the possible values that a variable, argument or object property can take*.

The type `'textPrimary' | 'textSecondary'` means 'this variable can only take the value 'textPrimary' or 'textSecondary'.

The type `string` represents 'all the legal values of a string in JavaScript' - which includes 'textPrimary' and 'textSecondary', so these more specific types are redundant. Hence why TypeScript did the right thing and eliminated them.

Comment: What you say makes sense for the logical (compiler) point of view, but for the IDE autocompletion POV, it would be useful that type `'textPrimary' | 'textSecondary'`is suggested while not erroring if any other value is inputted